# What is higher representation theory?

Tags: rt.representation-theory, higher-category-theory

Can anyone please introduce higher representation theory?

By Yoneda embedding, we know that global dimension of finitely generated category $\bmod\Lambda$ of Artin algebra $\Lambda$ is no more than $2$. In 2007, Iyama developed the higher-dimensional Auslander–Reiten theory ([Higher-dimensional Auslander–Reiten theory on maximal orthogonal subcategories](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.aim.2006.06.002)), in which "higher-dimensional" means higher global dimension. Using higher Auslander–Reiten theory, we can generalize hereditary algebra to higher hereditary algebra ([Herschend, Iyama, and Oppermann - $n$-representation infinite algebras](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.aim.2013.09.023)), tilting theory to higher tilting theory ([Iyama and Oppermann - $n$-representation-finite algebras and n-APR tiling](https://folk.ntnu.no/opperman/n-apr.pdf)) and homological algebra to higher homological algebra ([Jasso - $n$-Abelian and $n$-exact categories](https://doi.org/10.1007/s00209-016-1619-8)).

I want to know some of the other **motivations** and importance of higher representation theory. Any answers are welcome.

Comment: I've heard the terms "higher Auslander-Reiten theory" and "higher homological algebra" in this context, but not "higher representation theory", which I think usually has a different meaning. In any case, I don't think that this question is specific enough to be suitable for this site. See https://mathoverflow.net/help/on-topic, especially "MathOverflow is not the appropriate place to ask somebody to write an expository article for you".

Comment: One warning: it is common in the categorification literature to use "higher representation theory" in a different sense (see https://www.dtubbenhauer.com/higherrep.html for example).